# Is it possible to use Git between two workstations, without a "central" repository?

Tags: git, push, git-push

I made the move from SVN to Git for some home programming, setting up a Git repository on my ReadyNAS drive. I then created a repository, which I cloned onto two different laptops.

These laptops both have changes that are committed but not pushed back to the central repository; this is because the central repository / NAS drive is on a boat somewhere and won't be seen for 6-8 weeks ! So my question is, in the meantime, I have both laptops on the same network and would like to push the local repository commits from one laptop to the other.

Is this possible ? I am running Windows on both laptops, and using the "Git Bash" installable on each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Even without an additional bare central repo on one of the two laptops (wich would replace the original central repo).

The only drawback when working without a bare central repo is that you cannot push back to a checked out branch. Say, you're working on **master** on both laptops and cloned the repo on laptop2 from laptop1.

Before pushing back changes from laptop2 to laptop1, you have to do a

```
laptop1> git checkout other_branch
```

on laptop1 first, before you can execute the push.:

```
laptop2> git push
```

Otherwise the push will fail 'cause you cannot push to a checked out branch.
After the push, check out master again on laptop1.

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly what I thought git could do, and the branch tip was very useful too. So in summary, with changes on both laptops, I shared my repo folder on laptop1, checked out a new "temp" branch, on laptop2 I mapped the shared folder over, and then did a pull and then a push against the repo, then on laptop 1 I checked out the master branch again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sure. A git repository is just a bunch of files and all you need is some way to access them. For example, you could set up a bare "central" repository on one computer's shared folder and then push/pull to/from it from both computer's local clones that you use for development.